# Syntax error with floats when inserting into a table

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

Im trying to insert data into a table using python but im getting a syntax error. Here is my table format.

```
mycursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE workers (
                 `ID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                 ` x` FLOAT NOT NULL,
                 ` y` FLOAT NOT NULL,
                 `z` FLOAT NOT NULL,
                 `Acc` int NOT NULL,
                 `Datasource` char(3) NOT NULL,
                 `Datatype` int(5) NOT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))""")
```

The table code works fine

Here is the data im trying to insert into those tables

```
mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO workers VALUES
(1,\ 
1.2720693 ,\
6.583606 ,\
6.8299093 ,\
3 ,\
"Acc" ,\
1)""")
```

This is the error im getting

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\ 
1.2720693 ,6.583606 ,6.8299093 ,3 ,"Acc" ,1)' at line 2
```

Comment: Also, you should _always_ name your fields during insert/select. All it takes is someone adding a field in the middle of the table and all of a sudden, things start breaking in new and hard to debug ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting back from the server is telling you the backslashes are are the problem.

```
mycursor.execute("""
                 INSERT INTO workers VALUE (1,                    
                 1.2720693,
                 6.583606,
                 6.8299093,
                 3,
                 "Acc",
                 1)
                 """)
```

Triple strings in python are designed for multiline strings so you don't need to handle line continuations with backslashes. You also have 7 field values in your `INSERT` statement but you only need 6 as `ID` column is auto-incrementing.

Comment: Thanks, also ill take on board what you said about the field values